# Node JS workers - any need for them?

Tags: node.js, message-queue

Forgive my ignorance, but coming from a Django/Python background I can see the huge benefit of having a Celery queue working through the slower processes in the background whilst the web interface is updated as quick as possible.

However, with Node working asynchronously, is the use case for a queue system diminished hugely?

For example:

1 - a user posts something to the site,
2 - the site responds, then mails an administrator.

In Django, you'd send off the admin mail to a task, to be executed later, and then respond to the request. Celery sends the mail in the background.

In Node, you call your mailer, then respond to the request. The mailer then sends a callback to say DONE or not, by which point the user is already viewing the response.

So why would I use a queue with Node? I'm guessing when things are more complex than this - it seems that for trivial things like transactional mails, it's not necessary..

Or am I misunderstanding how it works!?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're right, continuations are quite nice in node and if you're running everything in a single node process there is no immediate need for a queue.
However, as node is single threaded, node won't be able to handle any new incoming requests while it's busy sending that email or processing that task (if it's a cpu intensive task)

So if your tasks take a while to process cpu wise, it might still be worthwhile using an external queue and a seperate process to handle those tasks/messages.
If your tasks are io intensive and take a while because they are waiting for responses from other servers for example, then there's less of a need again as node deals well with io.

If you have a cpu intensive task, but you don't want to deploy a queue you could just create more node processes and machine instances and load balance across them, all letting them process these tasks. The disadvantage of this approach would be the you can't scale the website and background processing separately. (e.g. 5 instances dealing with web requests and a 2 worker instances)

Comment: So if I wanted to do something like call an external API to flesh out a users information - eg. do some reverse geocoding with a request call to Google's geocoder. This request wouldn't stall my Node process for the following incoming request? But if there was a lot of CPU use it would..?

Comment: You'll need to benchmark it, but yes. That's roughly the idea. Have a look here to get some idea of how much can be done while waiting for an io operation: http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~rcs/research/interactive_latency.html. Node only does 1 thing at a time, so if it's number crunching, it can't serve requests. As soon as you do any io, you free node to go off and do other stuff.

Comment: Rephrasing for (marginal) clarity: if your parallel execution involves a lot of waiting around for HTTP or file system requests to return, then node's built-in asynchronous I/O will be plenty enough parallelism for you. If your parallel execution involves running large calculations locally (transcoding video; running a simulation) then node's single-threaded nature will stall you out and you'll need to spin work off to a worker if possible.

Answer (score 4):

No, there are always use cases for queues, even in the Node world. A basic approach that I've seen several people use to varying degrees of success is using a Redis backed queue to store messages or tasks. You may have one Node process adding items to the queue, with another Node instance processing items from the queue. In addition, take a look at the node modules list for [queue modules](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-message-queue), and you'll see a decent amount of implementations.

Comment: I understand. I figured there must be a reason there was a lot of queue implementations, I did say I thought the use case was reduced rather than gone altogether...